# Удалить элемент внутри блока на JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Всем привет! Суть задачи немного сложнее, чем указано в заголовке, попробую объяснить.
Есть динамические блоки, которых может быть больше, может быть меньше. Как пример:

```
<div class="block">
  <p class="element">Элемент</p>
  <p class="element">Элемент</p>
  <p class="element">Элемент</p>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <p class="element">Элемент</p>
  <p class="element">Элемент</p>
  <p class="element">Элемент</p>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <p class="element">Элемент</p>
  <p class="element">Элемент</p>
  <p class="element">Элемент</p>
</div>
```

Нужно, сделать так: если это 1-й блок, то удаляем все элементы и оставляем только 1-й элемент. Если это 2-й блок, то удаляем все, кроме 2-го элемента и тд. Блоков может быть больше, может быть меньше. Но если 4 блока, то всегда будет 4 элемента, если 5 блоков, то 5 элементов. Помогите, прошу)

Comment: А что вы пытались сделать? В чем именно проблема?

Comment: покажите как должен выглядить конечный результат, я лично понял, что нужно оставлять элемент внутри блока, который соответствует индексу блока + 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно так:

```
const allBlock = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
allBlock.forEach( (block, index) => {
    const elements = block.querySelectorAll('p.element');
    elements.forEach( (el, idx) => {
        if( idx !== index ) el.remove();
    } );
} );
```

Только нужно быть внимательнее с совместимостью метод forEach для NodeList не поддерживается старыми браузерами. Если нужна совместимость лучше сделать по старинке:

```
var allBlock = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.block'));
allBlock.forEach( (block, index) => {
    var elements =  Array.prototype.slice.call(block.querySelectorAll('p.element'));
    elements.forEach( (el, idx) => {
        if( idx !== index ) el.remove();
    } );
} );
```

Comment: А еще можно так, для старых браузеров + у вас стрелочные функции ): [].forEach(allBlock, function (block, index) {});

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Да, стрелочные функции забыл поменять

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, можно так:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('div.block')].forEach((block, index) => {
  const children = [...block.children];
  const saved = children[index];
  for (const child of children) {
    if (child !== saved) child.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <p class="element">Элемент 1.1</p>
  <p class="element">Элемент 1.2</p>
  <p class="element">Элемент 1.3</p>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <p class="element">Элемент 2.1</p>
  <p class="element">Элемент 2.2</p>
  <p class="element">Элемент 2.3</p>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <p class="element">Элемент 3.1</p>
  <p class="element">Элемент 3.2</p>
  <p class="element">Элемент 3.3</p>
</div>
```